# how to prove Fréchet inequality

Tags: probability

There is a very obvious and basic probability inequality,
$$P(A_1\cup A_2\cup ... \cup A_n) \le \sum_{i=0}^n P(A_i)$$
$A_i$ is an event that happens with certain probability ($1\le i\le n$).

The upper bound is too loose, and I want to seek a tighter upper bound.

Define$$\widetilde{S_m}=\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_m\le n} P(A_{i_1}\cup A_{i_2}\cup\cdots\cup A_{i_m}),$$

If reach the inequality:
$$P(A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n)\le {\frac {\widetilde {S_{m+1}}}{\binom{m}{n-1}}}\le {\frac {\widetilde {S_m}}{\binom{m-1}{n-1}}},\quad m=1,2,...,n.$$
then can get a tight upper bound.

Anybody could give some hints about how to prove the above inequality ?

Comment: Perhaps you could start by showing what you've already thought of and why that doesn't work?  You've defined the problem nicely, but we have no idea where you're actually stuck in order to help you.  The question will likely be closed if you don't provide this kind of context, so it's a good idea to do so :)

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Don't make it more complicated than it is. It is quite easy to prove by induction.